# htaccess ignore rewriterule for subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

here's my htaccess settings for redirecting urls which don't start with "www." (on my LIVE-environment):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

i'm also running my mirrored testing environment on a subdomain called test.mydomain.com.
how can i disable this rule for it (as it would always redirect to the live environment)?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add `test` in your negative `RewriteCond` like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|test)\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Anubhava's answer worked for me with a small adjustment:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|test)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```